# How do you launch Spyder in Windows 11?

Tags: python, windows, spyder

I installed Spyder using the Windows installer here:

https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html

But it won't launch. There is no Start menu icon.

At the end of the Windows installation, "Launch Spyder", which displays a red Spyder 5 splash screen then nothing.

There is no Spyder in the Start menu. Digging around C:\Program Files\Spyder, I can find no clickable EXE or similar to launch it.

I even tried

C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\app>......\Python\python.exe start.py

at the command prompt, which again shows the red Spyder splash screen and then spits out a massive list of errors to the console:

```
C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\app>..\..\..\Python\python.exe start.py
fromIccProfile: failed minimal tag size sanity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 274, in <module>
    main()
  File "start.py", line 256, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1838, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\app\utils.py", line 289, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 747, in setup
    internal_plugins = find_internal_plugins()
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\app\find_plugins.py", line 40, in find_internal_plugins
    mod = importlib.import_module(entry_point.module_name)
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\plugins\pylint\plugin.py", line 22, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\plugins\pylint\confpage.py", line 16, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.pylint.main_widget import (MAX_HISTORY_ENTRIES,
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\plugins\pylint\main_widget.py", line 90, in <module>
    class CategoryItem(QTreeWidgetItem):
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\plugins\pylint\main_widget.py", line 102, in CategoryItem
    'icon': ima.icon("convention")
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder\utils\icon_manager.py", line 434, in icon
    qta.load_font('spyder', 'spyder.ttf', 'spyder-charmap.json',
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\qtawesome\__init__.py", line 280, in load_font
    return _instance().load_font(prefix, ttf_filename, charmap_filename, directory)
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\qtawesome\__init__.py", line 130, in _instance
    _resource['iconic'] = IconicFont(*_BUNDLED_FONTS)
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 338, in __init__
    self.load_font(*fargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 374, in load_font
    directory = self._get_fonts_directory()
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 593, in _get_fonts_directory
    fonts_directory = self._install_fonts(fonts_directory)
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 623, in _install_fonts
    shutil.copy(src_path, user_fonts_dir)
  File "shutil.py", line 418, in copy
  File "shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\rickr\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\codicon-charmap.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. When trying to open spyder in the environment I got the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\codicon.ttf
```

I fixed it by 'deleting' the file. Not actually, because I was scared I would break it. I cut them and moved them to some other location. When I opened spyder it worked. Looking back in the folder 'C:\Users\rickr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts'(the one at the end of the error), I found out a new version of the file was installed into the directory. This is most likely because of the following line:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 593, in _get_fonts_directory
fonts_directory = self._install_fonts(fonts_directory)
```

You see at the end of the error.

And yes, I said moving 'them', because when I moved the first I got a permissionerror for another file in the same directory. After I moved both into a useless map I could open spyder just fine