# Denied permission for fonts stops opening of spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I open spyder, but it stops while initiating. Launching spyder via the anaconda prompt shows the problem.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\codicon.ttf'
```

I'll explain the problem in this first part. If you know of a way to fix it you don't really need to read the second part. It's probably gonna be important, I have:

```
Anaconda:
    anaconda Command line client (version 1.12.1)
Windows 11 Home
Python 3.11
```

After searching SO I found someone with a similar problem here: [How do you launch Spyder in Windows 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984596/how-do-you-launch-spyder-in-windows-11/77678890#77678890)
You can find the full output there too. I checked and it's the same for me pretty much except for the filename. If you look there you'll find one answer, mine. But it's a temporary solution that needs to be done everytime you open spyder.

I was hoping someone could help with a solution since that's the only question about it, and it does not have any answers. I also think I can describe the problem a little clearer with the code provided beneath (the previous code was everything that doesn't have 'I made this one myself' commented)

## My DIY Solution

I answered that question with a workaround: cutting the file and pasting it in some other location. Doing so will install another file with the same name in its' previous location. I have to do this twice: for codicon.tff and materialdesignicons6-webfont.ttf, giving the same error with a different file.

I have even went into the shutil.py file and changed the code myself, to do this programmatically. However, for some reason this still requires me to launch spyder again, as it still throws the following error after the first launch:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\codicon.ttf'
```

Launching spyder a second time will not have this error appear. Making this work by launching spyder 3 times:

- One with the condicon.tff error
- One with the materialdesignicons6-webfont.ttf
- The last one, a succesfull launch of spyder

Here is the changed code, in shutil.py:

```
def copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True):
    """Copy data from src to dst in the most efficient way possible.

    If follow_symlinks is not set and src is a symbolic link, a new
    symlink will be created instead of copying the file it points to.

    """
    sys.audit("shutil.copyfile", src, dst)

    if _samefile(src, dst):
        raise SameFileError("{!r} and {!r} are the same file".format(src, dst))

    file_size = 0
    for i, fn in enumerate([src, dst]):
        try:
            st = _stat(fn)
        except OSError:
            # File most likely does not exist
            pass
        else:
            # XXX What about other special files? (sockets, devices...)
            if stat.S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode):
                fn = fn.path if isinstance(fn, os.DirEntry) else fn
                raise SpecialFileError("`%s` is a named pipe" % fn)
            if _WINDOWS and i == 0:
                file_size = st.st_size

    if not follow_symlinks and _islink(src):
        os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    else:
        with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
            try:
                with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
                    # macOS
                    if _HAS_FCOPYFILE:
                        try:
                            _fastcopy_fcopyfile(fsrc, fdst, posix._COPYFILE_DATA)
                            return dst
                        except _GiveupOnFastCopy:
                            pass
                    # Linux
                    elif _USE_CP_SENDFILE:
                        try:
                            _fastcopy_sendfile(fsrc, fdst)
                            return dst
                        except _GiveupOnFastCopy:
                            pass
                    # Windows, see:
                    # https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/7160#discussion_r195405230
                    elif _WINDOWS and file_size > 0:
                        _copyfileobj_readinto(fsrc, fdst, min(file_size, COPY_BUFSIZE))
                        return dst

                    copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)

            # Issue 43219, raise a less confusing exception
            except IsADirectoryError as e:
                if not os.path.exists(dst):
                    raise FileNotFoundError(f'Directory does not exist: {dst}') from e
                else:
                    raise
                    
            # Handle PermissionError, I made this one myself
            except PermissionError:
                # Check if the file name matches
                special_files = ["codicon.ttf", "materialdesignicons6-webfont.ttf"]
                if os.path.basename(dst) in special_files:
                    new_dst = create_folder_for_special_files(dst)
                    return new_dst  # Returning the new path after moving the file
    
                # Raise the original PermissionError if the file doesn't match
                raise

    return dst
```

I wrote the exception PermissionError myself, here's the create_folder_for_special_files function:

```
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
def create_folder_for_special_files(dst):
    #I made this one myself
    today_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    new_folder_path = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\fontstuff", today_date)
    os.makedirs(new_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.move(dst, os.path.join(new_folder_path, os.path.basename(dst)))
    return os.path.join(new_folder_path, os.path.basename(dst))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: delete the files in quesion.**

I think this applies exactly to your case. Spyder was unable to launch showing the following message,

> spyder PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\codicon.ttf'

Simply deleting the file made the job. Similar to what you report, then the same error referring to another font file popped up, but after deleting it as well, spyder worked just fine.

Regards,